# prisma.$queryRaw()` invocation:\n\n\nRaw query failed. Code: `42P18`. Message: `ERROR: could not determine data type of parameter $2

Tags: typescript, nestjs, prisma, prisma-binding

```
      const search = ''
      const skip = (+page - 1) * +pageSize;
      const findId = search ? +search : undefined;
      const data = await this.prismaService.$queryRaw`SELECT 
      rd."id",
      rd."eventType",
      COALESCE(rd.quantity, 0) AS quantity,
      COALESCE(exp.paid, 0) AS paid,
      COALESCE(cast(exs."totalSupplier" AS DECIMAL),0) AS "totalSupplier",
      COALESCE(CAST(ext."totalExpense" AS DECIMAL),0) AS "totalExpense",
      COALESCE(CAST(fi."totalIncome" AS DECIMAL),0) AS "totalIncome",
      COALESCE(CAST(fi."totalIncome" AS DECIMAL), 0) - COALESCE(CAST(ext."totalExpense" AS DECIMAL), 0) AS "totalNetincome"
      FROM "Order" rd
      LEFT JOIN 
      (SELECT COUNT(ep.status) as paid ,ep."orderId" FROM "Expense" ep WHERE ep."status" = 1 AND ep."deletedAt" IS NULL GROUP BY ep."orderId") exp ON exp."orderId" = rd."id"
      LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ep."supplierId") as "totalSupplier",ep."orderId" FROM "Expense" ep WHERE ep."supplierId" IS NOT NULL  AND ep."deletedAt" IS NULL GROUP BY ep."orderId") exs ON exs."orderId" = rd."id"
      LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT SUM(ep.price) as "totalExpense",ep."orderId" FROM "Expense" ep WHERE ep."deletedAt" IS NULL GROUP BY ep."orderId") ext ON ext."orderId" = rd.id
      LEFT JOIN 
      (SELECT SUM(fi.price) as "totalIncome" ,fi."orderId" FROM "FinalInvoice" fi WHERE fi."deletedAt" IS NULL GROUP BY fi."orderId") fi ON fi."orderId" = rd."id"
      WHERE (rd."id" = ${(search && +search) || null} OR ${(search && +search) || null} IS NULL) AND rd."deletedAt" IS NULL 
      ORDER BY rd."id" DESC LIMIT ${+pageSize} OFFSET ${skip}`;
```

this raw i use in idea it's working fine but when I try take it to prisma raw query it's not work.please kindly help me if you have the same problem.Thanks